# Conditional libraryDependencies in SBT

Tags: sbt

I'd like to create conditional library dependency in build.sbt file.
I'm looking for similar behavior to maven profiles where I can enter a profile / system variable in the command line and have SBT define libraryDependencies according to it.

i.e. if system variable was supplied - add HBase client dependency else don't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ido

Comment: Are you aware of the [`Configuration`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Configuration-level+tasks) concept in `sbt`? It is not exactly like profiles in `maven` but the idea is the same, abstracting different configurations and gathering them under the same roof. It is a bit confusing at first but if you read the doc ,maybe 2 times :), then it'll become clear.

Comment: By the way note that you can always define your build in a `Scala` file inside `project` folder which gives you the freedom to do whatever you want. Such as reading system properties and adding libraries only when a certain system property is already set.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for your response. I've read about configuration in the link you provided (twice :)) but I don't see how it helps me to resolve my issue.
Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

Does this help?

```
val my_version = System.getProperty("my_version", "")
libraryDependencies ++= ( 
  if (my_version != "" ) 
    ("org.example.code" %% "my_library" % my_version) :: Nil
  else 
    Nil
  )
```

Only adds to library dependency, if a version is specified